# How to fetch the constant value from a column in Spark Dataframes

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this following dataframe where certain columns like version and datSetName are supposedly constants. I am trying to get these constants into a variable(version is of type float and dataSetName is string).

|id    |version  |dataSetName

```
|1     |1.0      | employee
|2     |1.0      | employee
|3     |1.0      | employee
|4     |1.0      | employee
```

using the following way gives me a Row

```
val datSetName = df.select("dataSetName").distinct.collect()(0)
```

what's the best way to get dataSetName and version into String and Float variables respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

**verison**

```
df
.select("version")
.distinct.map(_.getAs[Double](0))
.collect
.head
```

**dataSetName**

```
df
.select("dataSetName")
.distinct
.map(_.getAs[String](0))
.collect
.head
```

**version & dataSetName**

```
df
.select("version","dataSetName")
.distinct
.map(c => (c.getAs[Double](0),c.getAs[String](1)))
.collect
.head

(Double, String) = (1.0,employee) // Output
```

Comment: is there a way I can pass in desired column names in a list (eg: List("version", "dataSetName") and let map function do c.getAs[String](index) for all the elements in the list (assuming all the values are also String).
This will allow me to not hardcode the column names. plz suggest.

Comment: what's the best way to familiarize with all these DataFrame apis to know when to use map() vs another function based on the use case. I can really use some guidance.

Comment: Tried something like this but I know I'm missing something 
    `val colsList = inputColsList.map(name => col(name))

    df.select(colsList:_*).distinct
      .map(c => Map(colsList.map(c2 => c.getAs[String](c2._1))) )`
      .collect
      .head

Comment: can you comment on the above request please. thanks.

Comment: I got it working with this code :
`df.select(colsList:_*).distinct.map(c => { var lb =scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String,String)]();
 inputColsList.zipWithIndex.foreach(x => { lb += (( x._1,  c.getAs[String](x._1))) });lb.toMap }).collect.head`

Comment: This will only work on columns of type string..what if you have columns of type struct, map, or complex types

Comment: agree this only works for columns of type String and I would really like to extend it to work for all column types. Please let me know what your approach will be to solve that use case.

Comment: Ha.. that where I got stuck.. still trying.. will update if I get any solution..